# Django admin list_display property usage

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have models and their admin code at below. The question is how can I show the first three  `tag` of a book in its `list_display` property ?
I can show the tags while the book is editing but I would like to its 3 tags while the book are listed in the admin panel.

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class BookTag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book,null=False,blank=False)    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**admin.py**

```
class BookTagInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = JobTitleTag

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name')
    inlines = [ BookTagInline, ]

admin.site.register(Book,BookAdmin)
```

Could you give me any suggestion ?
Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a custom method on the admin class.

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'three_tags')

    def three_tags(self, obj):
        return obj.booktag_set.all()[:3]
```