# Access to user data from profile in admin.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to create an admin configuration to my new Profil class.

```
class Profil(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User) 
    birthdate = models.DateField("date de naissance", blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField("pays", max_length=64, blank=True)
```

And this is the admin.py of this class :

```
class ProfilAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user.username', 'user.email', 'country', 'user.is_staff')
    list_filter = ('user.date_joined', 'user.is_staff')
    search_fields = ('user.username', 'user.email', 'country', 'user.first_name')

admin.site.register(Profil, ProfilAdmin)
```

And of course, `'user.username'` doesn't work. How can I get the username of my user through my Profil class?

This is the solution and it looks good :

```
class ProfilAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('get_username', 'get_email', 'country')
    list_filter = ('get_date_joined', 'get_is_staff')
    search_fields = ('user__username', 'user__date_joined', 'user__is_staff')

    def get_username(self, obj):
        return obj.user.username
    get_username.short_description = 'User'
    get_username.admin_order_field = 'user__username'

    def get_email(self, obj):
        return obj.user.email
    get_email.short_description = 'Email'
    get_email.admin_order_field = 'user__email'

    def get_date_joined(self, obj):
        return obj.user.date_joined
    get_date_joined.short_description = 'Date joined'
    get_date_joined.admin_order_field = 'user__date_joined'

    def get_is_staff(self, obj):
        return obj.user.is_staff
    get_is_staff.short_description = 'Is staff'
    get_is_staff.admin_order_field = 'user__is_staff'
```

But now I get the following error during the makemigrations :

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'accounts.admin.ProfilAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[0]' refers to 'get_date_joined', which does not refer to a Field.
<class 'accounts.admin.ProfilAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[1]' refers to 'get_is_staff', which does not refer to a Field.
```

I understand that `is_staff` is a class method, but how can I access to it?

Comment: Are you getting an specific error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reach the object directly. Instead you'll have to use a custom method. The following should get you started:

```
class ProfilAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('get_username', )

    search_fields = ['user__username', ]

    def get_username(self, obj):
        return obj.user.username
    get_patient.short_description = 'User'
    get_patient.admin_order_field = 'user__username'
```

See also [Django admin list_display property usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674072/django-admin-list-display-property-usage).

Comment: In `list_filter` you can use double underscores to get to the related object, e.g. `user__is_staff`.

Comment: Not really, your post currently indicates `list_filter = ('get_date_joined', 'get_is_staff')`. These are methods and not fields; Django expects them to be fields. You can use the double underscore notation `__` to get to the respective related model/field.
Note this differs from list_display`.